# Can you get the size of a `sync.Pool`

Tags: go

Is there a way retrieving the size of a `sync.Pool` instance?

There’s an [interesting solution about how to implement a pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505830/how-to-implement-memory-pooling-in-golang) yourself, giving you full control.
But for most cases, I would like to just use `sync.Pool` and be done with it. Having the metrics would be nice though.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to implement your own freelist, sync.Pool can remove objects at any time.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way retrieving the size of a sync.Pool instance?

No.